# CMake with c++ and C# .NET6 SDK project using Pinvoke and copying DLLs

Tags: c#, cmake

I have a project with native components in c/c++, as well as some Windows managed projects using .NET which uses p/invoke to call into the native DLL's. So I would like to have a cmake generated .NET C# project which will build the managed code **and** copy the native DLL's it needs so it can be run without additional steps (e.g. to build and run tests directly in Visual Studio).

This was working with .NET 4.8 by adding a custom command to copy the DLL's, but I recently wanted to try out .NET 6 with an SDK-style vs project:

```
set_target_properties(${this_target} PROPERTIES
    DOTNET_SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk"
    DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK "net6.0")
```

My previous solution to copy the native DLLs was to define a custom function like this, which could copy the DLL's needed:

```
# in the native cmakelist for my dll with target name native_dll:
function(copy_native_dlls target output_directory)
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${build_binaries_path}/$<CONFIG>/native_dll/native1.dll ${output_directory}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${build_binaries_path}/$<CONFIG>/native_dll/native1.pdb ${output_directory}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${build_binaries_path}/$<CONFIG>/native_dll/native2.dll ${output_directory}
        DEPENDS native_dll
        COMMENT "copying native DLLs"
    )
endfunction()
```

And in each managed project, I would add this when I needed it:

```
copy_native_dlls(${this_target} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${this_target}>)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to move to .NET 6 with the SDK-style projects, I can no longer use `add_custom_command`: [DOTNET_SDK documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/DOTNET_SDK.html)

> Note The Visual Studio Generators in this version of CMake have not yet learned to support add_custom_command() in .NET SDK-style projects. It is currently an error to attach a custom command to a target with the DOTNET_SDK property set.

Is there some other way to maybe add a .DLL that is built in my project to another project so that it will be *copied* to the output directory when I build it? I'm hoping there is some way to point to these dlls in cmake and set up the dependencies properly

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds wrong but only way that I can make it work is this

```
add_custom_target(${this_target}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
  "$<TARGET_FILE:${TARGETFILE}>"
  "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${TARGETDIR}>"
)
set_target_properties(${this_target} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.7.1"
    VS_GLOBAL_ResolveNuGetPackages "false")
add_dependencies(${TARGETDIR} ${this_target})
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is how I handled it:

Have a dummy csproj like my_native_dll_helper.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{8CC13F24-535E-4B06-850B-7AD7C89453C7}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    
    <ManagedAssembly>true</ManagedAssembly>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;RelWithDebInfo;MinSizeRel</Configurations>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>$(BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\$(Configuration)\my_managed_path</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\$(Configuration)\my_native_dll.dll">
      <Link>my_native_dll.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\$(Configuration)\my_native_dll.pdb">
      <Link>my_native_dll.pdb</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory Condition="Exists('$(BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\$(Configuration)\my_native_dll.pdb')">PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then create it as an external project in cmake

```
include_external_msproject(my_native_dll_helper my_native_dll_helper.csproj)
add_dependencies(my_native_dll_helper my_native_dll)
```

And have that as a dependency on the generated managed project.

Note that the "my_managed_path" part above is where the generated project is copying binaries so this will copy the native DLL's to the same place.